# texlive 2016 installation process can't find kpsewhich, but the file exists

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu, kpsewhich

My texlive installation seems not to be working, but in a weird way.
Here is the last bit copied from [the log](http://metameso.org/~joe/install-tl.log) that was generated.  I'm installing from `install-tl-20170413` onto Ubuntu 16.04.  The specific command I ran was `sudo ./install-tl`.

```
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap line 22.
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap line 28.
./install-tl: updmap-sys --nohash failed: 
re-running mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config ...
setting up ConTeXt cache: running mtxrun --generate ...done
/usr/bin/env: 'texlua': No such file or directory
./install-tl: mtxrun --generate failed: 
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...done
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil line 17.
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil line 25.
./install-tl: fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all failed: 
running path adjustment actions
finished with path adjustment actions
running package-specific postactions
postaction install script for dvipdfmx: perl /tlpkg/tlpostcode/dvipdfmx.pl
postaction install script for ptex2pdf: perl /tlpkg/tlpostcode/ptex2pdf-tlpost.pl
postaction install script for xetex: perl /tlpkg/tlpostcode/xetex.pl
finished with package-specific postactions
```

The first part where it complains that it can't find `kpsewhich` is somewhat suspect, because the file exists:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 83424 Apr  7  2016 /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
```

Is there a way to recover the installation?  I've just upgraded my Ubuntu, because an earlier attempt today talked about "shared library woes".  That message has gone away.

---

**Update: permissions, as requested**

```
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Mar 31 03:48 /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 31 03:19 /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/2016/
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Mar 31 03:49 /usr/local/texlive/2016/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/2016/
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Mar 31 03:49 /usr/local/texlive/2016/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 31 03:19 /usr/local/texlive/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 4096 Mar 31 03:19 /usr/local/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /usr/
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4096 Aug  4  2015 /usr/
[joe@localhost togetherly]$ ls -ld /
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 root root 4096 Apr  4 19:51 /
```

Comment: What's your `$PATH`?

Comment: As root, `# echo $PATH` produces
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux`

Comment: You should also add the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux` and, possibly, of all parent directories: I suspect some permission issues.

Comment: I've added the permissions as requested.  I'm currently running the installation again, having in the mean time successfully installed the Ubuntu-packaged version of `texlive`.  Perhaps Ubuntu brings in some library dependencies that were missing.  Since I'm running the install command as root, permissions seem somewhat unlikely TBH!

Comment: Consider the possibility of installing texlive in your home directory. Then, you do not need root (and should NOT use sudo). I have it installed that way (2016), in Ubuntu 16.04. Additional tricks needed to use a GUI, but all documented here and there on the web.

Comment: @RobtA I am installing it system wide for multiple users.

Comment: Yes, the new Texlive installation has gone fine.  This suggests that the list of dependencies in this highly-rated Q&A item https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1 is not complete anymore.  But b/c the debugging messages are not clear at this point it is anyone's guess what libraries were missing...

Comment: Missing libs sounds strange for vanilla tl. I've never had to install extra libs to install tl or use it. It needed extra libs for Perl-doc, perl-tk and to build the equivs package, but these are not related to the functionality of a tl installation

Comment: I saw this when the texlive installer built binaries that were incompatible with the underlying OS, specifically Alpine (in a Docker container). Basic info:

`ldd kpsewhich` gives 
`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fbf57863000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fbf57863000)`
`file kpsewhich` gives
`kpsewhich: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9ba13353293c65f11b906c6e058dce2cd87c0610, stripped` I gave up and went back to using CentOS for this particular system.